# Error while forcing encoding in text file

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I'm trying to do a little challenge where you have to decode a 'Alien Message' located [here](http://www.iflscience.com/space/astrophysicist-has-asked-internet-decode-alien-message)

What I'm trying to do is force the encoding into ACSII in an attempt to decode the message here's what I have so far:

```
def gather_info
  file = './lib/SETI_message.txt'
  gather = File.read(file)
  packed = [gather].pack('b*')
  encoding_forced = packed.encode(Encoding::ASCII)
  File.open('packed.txt', 'a+'){ |s| s.puts(encoding_forced) }
end
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
main.rb:5:in `encode': "\xFF" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
        from main.rb:5:in `gather_info'
        from main.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea what this error means can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong, and how to go about fixing the encoding?

**UPDATE:**

I've discovered that the character encoding is IMB437 for the message using the following:

```
  file = './lib/packed.txt'
  gather = File.read(file)
  puts gather.encoding
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with trying to encode the unpacked string to ASCII is that while the unpacked string is 8 bits (256 possible characters), **[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) covers only 7 bits** (128 characters). So there is no way ruby can know how to encode (and possibly display) "characters" having their byte value above 127 and that's why you get the conversion error.

Anyway, converting the binary numbers to letters based on the ASCII table seems not the best approach for this type of task (unless the aliens used the ASCII table too :) ). I guess you need to work with the data as with numbers only.

Comment: `unless the aliens used the ASCII table too :)` Haha that's awesome, alright so basically Ruby isn't gonna help me here is what you're telling me?

Comment: No no, I just wanted to say that there is probably no point in trying to convert the bit string to letters, as there is always some encoding involved. I guess that instead the task is to understand the "alien ABC" that must somehow be inherent in the message... and that the ABC will more probably involve only numbers, not letters. It seems to me that the message can be split into an array of "lines", judging just from looking at it and seeing that there seem to be repetitions every few hundred bits... But I'm just guessing...

Comment: Well I've figured out from an hour ago that converting it to UTF-8 does nothing except throw a winky face like the file is mocking me. So that's irritating lol, thanks for your help